# How to fill in a table in react with an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, object

I have a pretty simple question, but couldnt deal with it yet.
The first code works, while the second just give me empty table cells. What is the reason for that and how can I put data into table without assigning to anything?

```
const prods = [
    {id: 1, name: 'product1', cost: 100},
    {id: 2, name: 'product2', cost: 200},
    {id: 3, name: 'product3', cost: 300},
];

function App() {
    const rows = prods.map(function(item) {
        return <tr key={item.id}>
            <td>{item.name}</td>
            <td>{item.cost}</td>
        </tr>;
    });
    
    return <table>
        <tbody>
            {rows}
        </tbody>
    </table>;
}
```

```
const prods = [
    {id: 1, name: 'product1', cost: 100},
    {id: 2, name: 'product2', cost: 200},
    {id: 3, name: 'product3', cost: 300},
];

function App() {
    
    return <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr key={prods.id}>
            <td>{prods.name}</td>
            <td>{prods.cost}</td>
        </tr>;
        </tbody>
    </table>;
}
```

Comment: prods is an array, `prods.id`, `prods.name`, etc... are all `undefined` since those properties do not exist on type `Array` .

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access a property value of an object inside an array of object with out iterating it's items, which will result undefined. In your case, you need to map over your array of objects using the **Map** method, please refer to this [url](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) so you can get to know more about rendering multiple components using the map method in React.

Answer (score 0):

You will see an empty row which may be invisible. But you can check it in browser dev tool.

Why? It's simple. You have not printed at all.

`prods` is an array. But in your render method (`return <table> ...`), you printed `prods.name` which is `undefined`.

So please change to see a row.

```
<td>prods[0].name</td>
...
```

Correct one is following:

```
function App() {

  return <table>
    <tbody>
    {prods.map(prod) => <tr key={prod.id}>
      <td>{prod.name}</td>
      <td>{prod.cost}</td>
      </tr>}
    </tbody>
  </table>;
}
```